# Need to run the code again if it fails, is there anyway out?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i have written a selenium automation code however it is very unstable because of the Salesforce website ,
i need some expertise in my code.
i wanted to know how i can re run the code if it fails.
below is my code ,
i will not able able to share some part of my code.
i was trying to you for loop however i was not able to make the correct use of it ,
i even tried the while loop but i dont  know how it works.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd
#rom glob import glob
from pathlib import Path
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
import win32com.client as win32
import warnings
warnings. filterwarnings("ignore")
#import sqlalchemy as sa

# PRE REQUSIT
today = date.today()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days = 1)
yesterday1 = yesterday.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
yesterday2 = yesterday.strftime('%d%m%y')
loginfmt= 'q'4sag 
#passward= 'av erg'
passward= 'wergwn'
search= 'ws'ergwerg
sql_userid='asdadsgfsdg'
sql_pwd= 'z5xv154fxgv'

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.dir', r"\\abc\bcd\adff\asfg\\python basics\web scraping\salceforce code\salesforcecode3downloads")
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile', 'text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml,application/xls,application/csv')
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml,application/xls,application/csv')
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force', False)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen', False)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting', False)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.manager.useWindow', False)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete', False)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone', False)
fp.set_preference("dom.forms.number", False)
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml,application/xls,application/csv,,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')

html_body2='<div>Hi Team,<br/> File saved to path:- <a href= "\\\\\abc\bcd\adff\asfg\dashboard">"[0o0]" </a> <br>  File uploaded successfully <br><br></div><div> Thanks & Regards,.<br> BIA Team </div>'

html_body3='<div>Hi Team,<br/> Automation failed please upload the file manually.<br><br></div><div> Thanks & Regards,.<br> BIA Team </div>'



to = ('bfdds'';''safsdg')

def file_s():
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To =  to
    mail.CC = 'abc'
    mail.Subject = 'Good will Automation successfull'
    mail.Body = 'Message body'
    mail.HTMLBody = html_body2 #this field is optional

    # To attach a file to the email (optional):
    #attachment  = "Path to the attachment"
    #mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)

    mail.Send()

def file_f():
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To =  to
    mail.CC = 'abc'
    mail.Subject = 'Good will Automation Failed'
    mail.Body = 'Message body'
    mail.HTMLBody = html_body3 #this field is optional

    # To attach a file to the email (optional):
    #attachment  = "Path to the attachment"
    #mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)

    mail.Send()


try:
    
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path =(r"\\abc\bcd\adff\asfg\\Desktop\python basics\geckodriver.exe"),firefox_profile=fp,service_log_path=r'\\abc\bcd\adff\asfg\\python basics\web scraping\salceforce code\geckodriver.log')
    #browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path =(r"\\abc\bcd\adff\asfg\\Desktop\python basics\chromedriver.exe"))
    #browser = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=(r"\\abc\bcd\adff\asfg\\Desktop\python basics\msedgedriver.exe"))
    website_URL ="https://h3g.my.salesforce.com"
    browser.get(website_URL)
    
    # ACTUAL CODE
    WebDriverWait(browser, 30, poll_frequency=5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="i0116"]'))).send_keys(loginfmt)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]').click()
    WebDriverWait(browser, 30, poll_frequency=5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="passwordInput"]'))).send_keys(passward)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="submitButton"]').click()
    #WebDriverWait(browser, 5, poll_frequency=2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="idBtn_Back"]'))).click()
    #time.sleep(10)
    WebDriverWait(browser,30, poll_frequency=5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="idBtn_Back"]'))).click()
    #browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idBtn_Back"]').click()
    time.sleep(20)
    
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/button").click()
    
    goodwill= 'Goodwill Credit Report'
    
    
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="slds-input"]').send_keys(goodwill)
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/search_dialog-instant-results-list/div/search_dialog-instant-result-item[1]/div[1]/div[2]/span").click()
    
    time.sleep(7)
    iframe3=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@title=\'Report Viewer\']") #(//iframe[@title='Report Viewer'])[2] 
    browser.switch_to.frame(iframe3)
    #//iframe[@title=\'Report Viewer\']
    time.sleep(240)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/button").click()
    
    
    #WebDriverWait(browser,30, poll_frequency=5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[9]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/button/span[3]'))).click()
    #browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/button/span[3]").click()
    #browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[9]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/button/span[3]').click()
    
    fnd_ele = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[9]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/button/span[3]')
    fnd_ele.click()
    
    WebDriverWait(browser,30, poll_frequency=5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/bodydiv/div/div[2]/div/div/span/a'))).click()
    #browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/span/section/div/div/span/a").click()
    
    WebDriverWait(browser,30, poll_frequency=5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@class="slds-input"]'))).send_keys(yesterday1)
    #browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="slds-input"]').send_keys(yesterday1)
    
    #time.sleep(5)
    WebDriverWait(browser,30, poll_frequency=5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//div[@class = "filter-date-picker slds-form-element slds-m-to_none"]/div/div/div/div/input[@class="slds-input"]'))).send_keys(yesterday1)
    #browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class = "filter-date-picker slds-form-element slds-m-to_none"]/div/div/input[@class="slds-input"]').send_keys(yesterday1)
    
    #time.sleep(3)
    WebDriverWait(browser,30, poll_frequency=5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/spandiv/footer/div[2]/button[2]'))).click()
    #browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/bodydiv/div/footer/div[2]/button[2]').click()
    
    
    WebDriverWait(browser,30, poll_frequency=5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/div/div/button'))).click()
    #browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[9]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/div/div/button').click()
    
    #time.sleep(20)
    WebDriverWait(browser,30, poll_frequency=5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/htmldiv/ul/li[3]/a'))).click()
    #browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/span/div/ul/li[3]/a').click()
    
    
    main_window_handle = browser.current_window_handle
    print("Current window",main_window_handle)
    browser.switch_to.default_content()
    
    WebDriverWait(browser,10, poll_frequency=5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/buton[2]/span'))).click()
    
    time.sleep(10)
    #WebDriverWait(browser,10, poll_frequency=5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/section/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/ul[2]/li[2]/div[2]/buton/lightning-primitive-icon'))).click()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/section/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/ul[2]/li[2]/div[2]/buttn/lightning-primitive-icon").click()
    
    time.sleep(20)
    browser.quit()
    
    
    " EDITING THE FILE "
    
    def get_latest_file(src_path,extension,method='st_mtime'):
        """ 
        Takes in a raw path and extension to parse over
        returns a single file with the last modified date
    
        methods:
        st_mtime: It represents the time of most recent content modification. It is 
        expressed in seconds.
        st_ctime: It represents the time of most recent metadata change on Unix 
        and creation time on Windows. It is expressed in seconds.
        """
    
        extension = extension if extension[0] != '.' else extension[1:]
    
        files = (Path(src_path).glob(f'*.{extension}'))
    
        if method == 'st_mtime':
            file_dictionary = {file : file.stat().st_mtime for file in files}
        elif method == 'st_ctime':
            file_dictionary = {file : file.stat().st_ctime for file in files}
        else:
            raise Exception(f'{method} not valid for this function')
    
        max_file = max(file_dictionary, key=file_dictionary.get)
    
    
        return max_file
    
    latest = get_latest_file(r'C:\\abc\bcd\adff\asfg\python basics\web scraping\salceforce code\salesforcecode3downloads',extension='xlsx',method='st_mtime')
    print(latest)
    df = pd.read_excel(latest)
    
    #df= pd.read_excel("Complaints-2022-03-09-07-52-48.xlsx")
    df.drop([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],inplace=True)
    df.columns = df.iloc[0] 
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    df2=df.iloc[1:]
    df3=df2.iloc[:,1:]
    df3.drop(df3.tail(1).index,inplace=True)
    df4=df3.drop(df3.columns[1], axis=1)
    
    df4.to_csv(r'\\abc\bcd\adff\asfg\Goodwill Credit Report-'+yesterday2+'.csv', header=True, index=False,)
    df4.to_csv(r'\\abc\bcd\adff\asfg\Goodwill Credit Report-'+yesterday2+'.csv', header=True, index=False,)
    print("Excel file edited")
    #df3.columns
    
    df5 =  df4.drop(['Dispute Id: Case Number','Date','Status','Installment Amount','Total Installments','Service Terms','Service Amount','Service End Date','Mode',
    'Notes'], axis = 1)
    
    
    conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
    r'SERVER=something;'
    r'DATABASE=something;'
    r'Uid='+sql_userid+';'
    r'Pwd='+sql_pwd+';')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('Truncate table somethingTemp')
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    print("file truncate succesfull")
    
    driver='SQL Server Native Client 11.0'
    params = quote_plus(r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
    r'SERVER=something;'
    r'DATABASE=something;'
    r'Uid='+sql_userid+';'
    r'Pwd='+sql_pwd+';')
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s' % params)
    
    # converting the created date column to str then changing it to date time and formating it dd-mm-yy
    df5['Created Date']=df5['Created Date'].astype(str)
    df5['Created Date']=pd.to_datetime(df5['Created Date'], format="%d/%m/%Y")
    
    df5.to_sql('C_VisionPay_Temp', con = engine, if_exists = 'append', index = False)
    
    
    df5['Created Date']
    conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
    r'SERVER=something;'
    r'DATABASE=something;'
    r'Uid='+sql_userid+';'
    r'Pwd='+sql_pwd+';')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    params=date(yesterday.year,yesterday.month,yesterday.day)
    storedProc = "something"
    cursor.execute( storedProc, params )
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    print("file executed sucessfully " )
    
    file_s()
    
except:
    file_f()
```

Comment: you can try the simplest and most trivial idea, wrap the function call with a `try: foo() break except: pass` and wrap that in a `while True`, it'll run forever until `foo()` fully worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of sleeps here, which is a tell-tale sign of poorly written automation code. This will expose the automation to the unwanted failures which you're describing.

Is there any reason why we're using sleep's instead of more appropriate explicit or fluent waits?

I would personally advise against going down the path of trying to rerun failed automation tests until they pass, that's a rabbit hole which sounds messy. Instead I'd focus on making the code sleepless and robust. There's a wealth of information around on why using sleeps is a bad idea.

Another couple of observations if I may:

1. Xpaths like `/html/body/div[9]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/button` should be avoided, these are prone to change and will add brittleness to the code
2. There are examples where id's are being dealt with by proxy via xpath, for example: `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]').click()`. We're better off cutting out the middleman and finding the element by id directly. For example: `browser.find_element_by_id('idSIButton9').click`
3. There's a lot of repeated code, if one small thing changes, we may have to make many changes to correct it. Ideally we want to only have to make that change in one place

All the best

Comment: i really appreciate your feedback , and will try not to repeat my mistakes. however would like to tell you why i have uses sleep is because this salesforce lightning page has bad hobbit for taking longer time for loading some time the website takes 2 minits to load the data and in some cases it takes 15 minits ,

Comment: so i have took average wait in some cases , and given time to the website to load , i could have used EC.element_to_be_clickable or EC.visibility_of_element_located , however in this case the web page loads but the data is not visible the inner iframe doesn't load  . im not an expert , im still learning , and trying to find the alternative to time.sleep . i will definitely take you feedback in a positive way and change my code.

Comment: FluentWait is perfect for what you are describing. With fluent waits we can set:

The expectation, 
The timeout, 
The polling rate, 
and whether we want to ignore any exceptions during this period.

In the case where we want to wait 15 minutes for something to happen, we can configure our timeout to 15 minutes - I'd suggesting setting this higher than 15 minutes if it takes longer on a bad day, we might take our worse case scenario and add maybe 10% to it as a safety buffer. Then maybe set our polling rate to 1-5 seconds as we don't want to check very frequently.

Comment: For the situations you describe where the webpage loads, but data within the iframe doesn't load, we can overcome this by adding an additional wait inside the iframe. Example steps might look like this:

1. Wait for all elements on the webpage to load
2. Step inside the iframe
3. Wait for all elements inside the iframe to load
4. Finally, interact with those elements inside the iframe